# Last digit minus remaining numbers

Tags: java

How can i minus the last digit to the remaining numbers i input? ex. "`1234`" is my input, "`4`" is the last digit and the remaining numbers are "`123`". To simplify its "`123 - 4 = 119`" the output should be 118. I'm kinda lost and i am beginner in programming hoping someone can help me. I've already know how to get the last digit of the input numbers using this code `int lastDigit = Math.abs(number-((int)(number/10))*10);`. My only problem is i don't know how to minus the last digit to remaining numbers.

- Input `1234`
- Solution `123-4=118`
- Output `118`

Comment: Show your [mcve] code showing your own attempt. Doing this will help both you and us.

Comment: You can get the last digit a lot easier than that: `number % 10`

Comment: `123 - 4 = 118`!!! at least post a valid example.

Comment: `num / 10 - num % 10` thats pretty much it

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi except that `123 - 4 != 118`

Comment: @forpas it does work in base 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int result = number/10 - number%10;